# Create set of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, set

I am trying to create a set of vectors in C++. I want the vectors `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` to be considered equal in the set. So both should not exist in the set. Also a vector can have the same element multiple times, so `[1,2]` and `[1,2,2]` should not be equal.

I tried the following code:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> vt1{1,2};
    vector<int> vt2{2,1};
    set<vector<int>> st;
    st.insert(vt1);
    st.insert(vt2);
}
```

But after running this code, I found that the set contains both `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`.

Comment: vectors are compared by element, and so it's not the same

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use inner `std::multi_set` and really need `std::vector` (and keep original order of `std::vector`), you might provide custom comparer:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

struct compare_as_set
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(std::vector<T> rhs, std::vector<T> lhs) const
    {
        std::sort(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
        std::sort(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());

        return rhs < lhs;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vt1{ 1,2 };
    std::vector<int> vt2{ 2,1 };
    std::set<std::vector<int>, compare_as_set> st;
    st.insert(vt1);
    st.insert(vt2); // insertion would fail as vt2 is equivalent to vt1
    std::cout << st.size() << std::endl; // So output is 1
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/o4kxkn)

Comment: You copying vectors every time comparator is called. This can be very inefficient with big vectors, in this case its better to use some other methods, e.g. convert vectors to sets/multisets before inserting in set.

Comment: @sklott: Indeed, if OP can use `std::multi_set` instead of `std::vector`, it is the way to go. but **If** OP wants to keep `std::vector` (with original order), copy (but even worse `sorting`) seems needed at some place. Wrapping in a class using something like `std::set<std::pair<std::multi_set<int>, std::vector<int>>, CompFirst>` would be another option to avoid some copies (in exchange with memories).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the vectors `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` aren't the same. Perhaps a set of vectors isn't what you want. Maybe try a different data structure, such as a set of sets:

```
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<int> vt1{ 1,2 };
    std::set<int> vt2{ 2,1 };
    std::set<std::set<int>> st;
    st.insert(vt1);
    st.insert(vt2);
    std::cout << st.size() << std::endl;
}
```

If the inner sets should be able to contain the same element multiple times, make them [multisets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset):

```
std::multiset<int> vt1{ 1,2 };
std::multiset<int> vt2{ 2,1 };
std::set<std::multiset<int>> st;
```

Comment: I did think about set of sets. But the inside data structure can have duplicate elements.

Comment: Then `set` of `multi_set`: `std::set<std::multi_set<int>>`